# How to delete rows from multiple tables using SQL query in asp.net?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have 2 tables that I want to delete data from: User table and feedback table.

Here are my codes (which doesn't work):

```
  string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

    string strtext = "DELETE FROM [User] WHERE Username = @user";
    strtext += "DELETE FROM Feedback WHERE Username = @user";
    strtext += "DELETE FROM Light WHERE Username = @user";
    strtext += "DELETE FROM Temperature WHERE Username = @user";
    strtext += "DELETE FROM Airquality WHERE Username = @user";
    strtext += "DELETE FROM Bodycondition WHERE Username = @user";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strtext, myConnect);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@user"].Value = txtdeleteuser.Text;

    myConnect.Open();
    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Is there any way to delete the SAME data from both tables using 1 SQL query in asp.net?

Comment: How is it a duplicate question? This one involves asp.net, not just sql alone. I can't seem to "seperate the sql queries" in asp.net as mentioned in the suggested duplicated answer.

Comment: You need to make this into two queries. The simplest path is to replace that AND with a ;. In other words your strtext will contain two individual delete statements.

Comment: You also need to read about the USING statement. Your connection and command should be inside those to properly dispose of those objects.

Comment: Hi, I've made changes using multiple queries but it still doesn't work. There is an error `Must declare the scalar variable "@userDELETE" ` I think that the mutlple queries can't work in asp.net. @sean lange

Comment: You don't have semicolons in your query, you have a whole bunch of string concatenation statements. Your string should be "DELETE from [User] Where Username = @user; Delete from ..." You are confusing sql from your c# code.

Comment: Thanks very much! It works now!